# How to get Fields from store in ExtJS5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, extjs5

I created a normal window in **ExtJS5** which has one grid and one button. I want to get store field items from grid store and want to do another functionality.

When i get **store.fields,** it shows null. But if i get in **ExtJS3**, then it works proper.

In below image, I am getting store fields or fields items in ExtJS3.

[image]

Here is my code (ExtJS5)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
                var States = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
                {
                    fields: ['value'],
                    data:
                    [
                        { "value": "HR" },
                        { "value": "DL" },
                        { "value": "RJ" }
                    ]
                });

                var window = new Ext.Window({
                    id: 'grdWindow',
                    width: 400,
                    title: 'Grid Samples',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            layout: 'fit',
                            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'Submit',
                                    handler: function () {
                                        var storeFields = Ext.getCmp('grdSample').getStore().fields;
                                        //storeFields get null;
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'grid',
                                    id: 'grdSample',
                                    store: States,
                                    columns: [
                                        {
                                            header: 'Name',
                                            dataIndex: 'value'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }]
                }).show();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grid.getStore().getModel().getFields() should do what you want.

Comment: Hi Bhutten. Your answer may correct and we can also get  - grid.getStore().model.prototype.fields. Both returns same value. But i need same (if possible) as it returns in ExtJS3. Both have a lot of differences. Even if we get items ' grid.getStore().getModel().getFields().items '  then it returns same. I have  updated image for better understanding. Can you please have a look on it.

Comment: If you're looking to get the exact same private data from ExtJS 5 as you get from ExtJS 3 then you're out of luck IMO. (Also it's a bad idea, even if it was possible).

Comment: Okay. I think, it also doesn't return actually that thing, as i am getting in ExtJS 3. I didn't test completely yet. But if required functionality can be implemented also by this, then it may be 100% corrected. Otherwise we need to find another way to do this. Just wait some time, I will definitely share with you.

Comment: Yeah - really do not use private values. Sencha reserves the right to move those values around - a lot. Stick with documented methods - you'll have enough pain with upgrades anyway.

Comment: Hi Robert. Can you explain more about private values. I don't have much information about it.